# Removing duplicate integers from Array in C++

Tags: c++

Here is my array: Arr[8] = {24, 30, 30, 32, 32, 36, 36, 36};

I am trying to eliminate the duplicate numbers from Arr using C++. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: use a <map> datastructure (Hashtable) to filter out the duplicates

Comment: Why `map`? Put them in a `set` and print them.

Comment: [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

Comment: possible duplicate of question [using-a-function-to-remove-duplicates-form-an-array-in-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501982/using-a-function-to-remove-duplicates-form-an-array-in-c)

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: Map is not essentially hashtable. In MSVC implementation it is red black tree. Moreover, it is complex way. He can simply sort array and remove duplicates by simple ordering

Comment: I'd go for dumping them in a `set` as well. `map` doesn't make much sense in this case.

Comment: yes, it is sorted.

Comment: In which case, plump for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom. You can use `std::begin(Arr)` etc.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do your homework yourself?

Answer (score 2):

```
sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
vec.erase( unique( vec.begin(), vec.end() ), vec.end() );
```

Comment: This is obviously designed for a container such as `std::vector`, not a C-style array like: `int[8]`.

Comment: @Jonas - It works perfectly for a C-style array.  Removal from an array involves updating the size. And here the new size is simply `unique(...) - arr`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I was trying to point out the use of `vec.erase` (and vec.begin() as oppose to using `std::begin(vec)`). Either way, this question has to be dube.